# In R: subset or dplyr::filter with variable from vector

Tags: r, subset, dplyr

```
df <- 
  data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:4],
             b=rnorm(4)
             )

vals <- c("B","D")
```

I can filter/subset `df` with values in `val` with:

```
dplyr::filter(df, a %in% vals)
subset(df, a %in% vals)
```

Both gives:

```
  a         b
2 B 0.4481627
4 D 0.2916513
```

What if I have a variable name in a vector, e.g.:

```
> names(df)[1]
[1] "a"
```

Then it doesnt work - I guess because its quoted

```
dplyr::filter(df, names(df)[1] %in% vals)
[1] a b
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

How do you do this ?

**UPDATE ( what if its dplyr::tbl_df(df) )**

Answers below work fine for data.frames, but not for dplyr::tbl_df wrapped data:

```
df<-dplyr::tbl_df(df)
dplyr::filter(df, df[,names(df)[1]] %in% vals)
```

Does not work (I thought `tbl_df` was a simple wrap on top of df ? )

This does work again:

```
dplyr::filter(df, as.data.frame(df)[,names(df)[1]] %in% vals)
```

**FINAL UPDATE: It works with tbl_df() using lazyeval::interp**

See AndreyAkinshin's solution below.

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar: as stated below, I need variable names from a char vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `df[,"a"]` or `df[,1]`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:4], b = rnorm(4))
vals <- c("B","D")

dplyr::filter(df, df[,1] %in% vals)
#  a         b
# 2 B 0.4481627
# 4 D 0.2916513

subset(df, df[,1] %in% vals)
#  a         b
# 2 B 0.4481627
# 4 D 0.2916513

dplyr::filter(df, df[,"a"] %in% vals)
#  a         b
# 2 B 0.4481627
# 4 D 0.2916513

subset(df, df[,"a"] %in% vals)
#  a         b
# 2 B 0.4481627
# 4 D 0.2916513
```

**Working with dplyr::tbl_df(df)**

Some magic with `lazyeval::interp` helps us!

```
df <- dplyr::tbl_df(df)
expr <- lazyeval::interp(quote(x %in% y), x = as.name(names(df)[1]), y = vals)

df %>% filter_(expr)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#   a        b
# 1 B 0.4481627
# 2 D 0.2916513
```

Comment: Yes of cause - but what if I dont know the position of the variable, only the variable name. I need to to with the var names in a vector like shown.

Comment: Beautiful. Thats it. Simple !

Comment: Funny, this does not work for tbl_df() wrapped data.

Comment: @ Veerendra Gadekar: on my machine I need to 'unwrap' before - see my update. But works fine for data.frame. Does it work on tbl_df(df) for you?

Comment: @user3375672 ok I see what you ment

Comment: @AndreyAkinshin: Yes thats magically (or what). Great, we solved everything then!

Comment: Perhaps this is a new feature since this comment was made, but isn't it better use a formula rather than `quote()`, since it will capture the environment and `quote()` doesn't.
`expr <- lazyeval::interp(~ x %in% y, x = as.name(names(df)[1]), y = vals)`

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to solve this problem in the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:4], b = rnorm(4))
vals <- c("B","D")
df %>% filter(!!sym(names(.)[1]) %in% vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.data` pronoun to select the column name -

```
library(dplyr)

col <- names(df)[1]
df %>% filter(.data[[col]] %in% vals)

#  a         b
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 B     -1.06
#2 D     -1.75
```

Or in base R -

```
df[df[[col]] %in% vals, ]
```