# refer to specific values of columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This answer is out there somewhere, but I'm having a hard time articulate it.

I want to refer to a subset a vector with a `dplyr` framework.  It's best explained with an example.

I'm trying to calculate something called "Delta E"

[image]

Which requires me to refer to one row (called "Control") in this example.

I've tried to find ways to refer to specific values within a column of a data.frame.

[In R: subset or dplyr::filter with variable from vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358953/in-r-subset-or-dplyrfilter-with-variable-from-vector)

Here's the example data:

```
df <- read.table(text="
sampleID     L     a     b
control   54.1  32.5  85.6
A         51.7  34.2  83.3
B         53.7  32.8  85.0
D         53.8  32.7  85.1", header=T)
```

And I'd like to use `dplyr` to get the end result, without doing anything to hacky.

```
df %>%
   mutate(deltaE = sqrt((Lc - L)^2 - (ac - a)^2 + (bc - b)^2)

  sampleID     L     a     b deltaE
  control   54.1  32.5  85.6  0    
  A         51.7  34.2  83.3  3.73 
  B         53.7  32.8  85.0  0.733
  D         53.8  32.7  85.1  0.614
```

Where `Lc = 54.1`, `ac = 32.5` and `bc = 85.6` which correspond to the control sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not super pretty, but you can do

```
df %>%
  mutate(deltaE = sqrt((L[sampleID=="control"] - L)^2 + 
                         (a[sampleID=="control"] - a)^2 +
                         (b[sampleID=="control"] - b)^2))
```

Or split it up into steps

```
df %>%
  mutate(isControl = sampleID=="control",
         Lc = L[isControl],
         ac = a[isControl],
         bc = b[isControl]) %>% 
  mutate(deltaE = sqrt((Lc - L)^2 + 
                         (ac - a)^2 +
                         (bc - b)^2)) %>% 
  select(-isControl, -Lc, -ac, -bc)
```